# Traefik routing with based on the protocol / scheme

Tags: docker, websocket, routes, traefik

I have two docker containers running in the same server with domain app.example.com,

REST container -  listening on port 80 for http://* requests
WEBSOCKET container - listening on port 90 for ws://* requests

I want calls to **http**://app.example.com routed to the REST container
and calls to    **ws**://app.example.com   routed to  the WEBSOCKET

how do I do this with traefik?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to route on scheme.

You can route on path, header, query, http Method, host, or ports.

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/basics/#matchers

Comment: I just noticed that websockets requests always have .../socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket in the url so i can probalby match on the "socket.io" in the path